# Mapping a 2 dimensional json array to java object

Tags: java, json

This question already has an answer here:

How to convert the following json string to java object? 5 answers
Converting JSON data to Java object 11 answers
I have to map below structure of json to Java Objcet What can be the best way to achieve it.

I am uploading an excel and excel can have up to 100 rows in the format below:

```
{        
   ["Range Start", "Range End", "Zone1", "Zone2", "Zone3", "Zone4", "Zone5"]    
   ["0", "1", "3", "9", "13", "17", "22"]
   ["2", "4", "5", "12", "17", "21", "27"]        
 }
```

I want to understand what can be the best way to model my Java Object which can consume this json structure. Here the labels represent excel columns while arrays with numbers are values of those columns for each row.

I can do it when json structure is like key-value pairs i.e. like below :

```
   {
      ["Range Start":"0", "Range End":"1", "Zone1":"3", "Zone2":"9", 
         "Zone3":"13", "Zone4":"17", "Zone5":"22"],        
       ["Range Start":"2", "Range End":"4", "Zone1":"5", "Zone2":"12", 
         "Zone3":"17", "Zone4":"21", "Zone5":"27"]                
   }
```

But I am not able to figure out how to parse when all columns names and row values come seperately.

Comment: This is not JSON. If the curly braces are in fact brackets, then you have an array of arrays of strings. So you can use a String[][], or a List<List<String>>.

Comment: @JBNizet   My json is complex, this is just part of json which is troubling me. Its the 2D array in my json. Yes I agree with your solution, but how can I map the column names to properites of java class.

Comment: But, even as part as a bigger JSON document, that's not JSON. Refresh the page and read my first comment.

Comment: @JBNizet how can I map column names which is coming at array[0][0] to my class object

Comment: As I said, you use a String[][] or a List<List<String>>, which matches with your (supposed) JSON structure. And once you jabe that array or list, you do whatever you want with it, using code that you write.